# 503 error but script continues running - how can I see the results?

Tags: php, http-status-code-503

I have a PHP script that takes a long time to run. After a few minutes I get a 503 error. But I've noticed that the code continues running (I have a log file that continues to be updated with timestamps way beyond the time I receive the 503 error.

Since the error is not really stopping the code, is there any way for me to not get the error so that I get to see the end result on the website instead of in the log file?

PS. It's a shared hosting and I don't have access to php.ini.

PPS. Do you know if the script would stop running if I close the 503 error tab? (I don't want to risk it, as I could get some errors if the script stops in the wrong time)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @bassxzero That doesn't help. Maybe because of the shared hosting.